# Subsequent weighted algorithm for comparison

Tags: math, algebra

I have two rows of numbers ...

1) 2   2   1    0   0   1

2) 1.5 1   0   .5   1   2

Each column is compared to each other. Lower values are better. For example Column 1, row 2's value (1.5) is more accurate than row 1 (2)

In normal comparison I would take to the sum of each row and compare to the other row to find the lowest sum (most accurate). In this case both would be equal.

I want to create two other comparison methods
When values ascend from column 1 they should be weighted more (col 2 should hold more weight than 1, 3 than 2 and so on)

Also the opposite

Originally I thought it would be best to divide the value by its position but that doesn't work correctly.

What would be the best way to do this for a row?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. First you say "Each column is compared to each other", then you go on to only compare values computed for the entire row. No column comparisons are done. Is that first statement correct?

Comment: No column comparison is actually done. Sum of each row is compared to another row. Lowest value being the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So all you're really doing is computing the product of your matrix with a weighting vector. See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) for more info on matrix multiplication.

I.e. your vector M is

```
M = | 2.0 2.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 |
    | 1.5 1.0 0.0 0.5 1.0 2.0 |
```

and in your first case the weighting vector w is:

```
w = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

the product of which gives you:

```
M x w = (6, 6)
```

which are the two scores for the two rows.

For an ascending weighting use something like :

```
w = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

which gives you:

```
M x w = (15, 22.5)
```

and for a descending weight you could use either:

```
w = (6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

or

```
w = (1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6)
```

(Note vectors are transposed for readability).

Answer (score 1):

Originally, all values have the same weight, so your factors for n values are all 1/n, so your sum is:

```
S = 1 * v_1 + 1 * v_2 + ... + 1 * v_n
```

Your try to divide the value by its position would be:

```
S = 1/1 * v_1 + 1/2 * v_2 + ... + 1/n * v_n
```

Which is still a valid approach, but does the opposite of what you want (column 1 gets most weight).

What you want is something like this:

```
S = 1/n * v_1 + 1/n-1 * v_2 + ... + 1/1 * v_n
```

You might also consider to start with 1/n+1 and end with 1/2 so the last value will be a bit less important.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have understood what you wanna do, but maybe it's this:

```
for (i=0, i<length, i++)
  difference += (a[i] - b[i]) * w[i];
```

w[] would be an array with the weights by column (e.g.: w={1,2,3,4,5}), although could well be any other value/function.

So in the end, if difference is higher than 0, a[] is better, and if it's lower than 0 is worse.